# mysql ndb_mgmd --no-nodeid-checks - Startup error

Tags: mysql, database, cluster-computing

I am having trouble starting up ndb_mgmd. Here's some information.

```
OS: Ubuntu 12.04LTS
MySQL -V: Ver 5.5.25a-ndb-7.2.7 for Linux on x86_64 (Source distribution)
Base Dir = /usr/local/mysql
Default MySQL Conf = /xconf/mysql/my.cnf
Default MySQL Data = /xdata/mysql
```

**/xconf/mysql/my.cnf**

```
[mysqld]
ndbcluster
socket=/xdata/mysql/mysql.sock

[mysqld_safe]
err-log=/xlog/mysqld.log
pid-file=/xdata/runtime/mysqld/mysqld.pid

[ndb_mgmd]
configdir=/xdata/mysql-cluster
config-file=/xdata/mysql-cluster/config.ini
```

**/xdata/mysql-cluster/config.ini**

```
[NDBD DEFAULT]
NoOfReplicas=2
DataDir=/xdata/mysql-cluster

# Management Node

[ndb_mgmd]
NodeId=1
HostName=192.168.2.100
DataDir=/xdata/mysql-cluster

# Storage Nodes

[ndbd]
NodeId=2
HostName=192.168.2.101

[ndbd]
NodeId=3
HostName=182.168.2.102

# SQL Nodes

[mysqld]
HostName=192.168.2.100

[mysqld]
HostName=192.168.2.101

[mysqld]
HostName=192.168.2.102
```

When I execute:

```
@xuser:/xdata/mysql-cluster$ ndb_mgmd
MySQL Cluster Management Server mysql-5.5.25 ndb-7.2.7
[MgmtSrvr] ERROR    -- Could not determine which nodeid to use for this node. Specify it with --ndb-nodeid=<nodeid> on command line
```

Any ideas as to why this is happening?

Comment: Is the host you're starting the manager on 192.168.2.100? It sounds like the manager is trying to start up, reading the config.ini and seeing that ip for the only manager slot and thinking it doesn't match. It could also be a cached config problem if you recently changed the ip. Use ndb_mgmd --initial to clear the binary config and force it to reload from the config.ini file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was I wasn't connected to the network of the cluster.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by not connected to the network of the cluster? I am having the same problem. @nick